# Change the pop-up order of overlapped points in Portal for ArcGIS / ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, display, arcgis-portal, order

For maps on ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Portal, is there any way to decide the pop-up display order of multiple completely overlapped points?

For example, two icons having the same Lat & Long in the same layer shown in the screenshots. It shows the point with UniqueID 684 is in the first pop-up window and the point with Unique ID 685 is in the second pop-up window, but the info in the second pop-up window is more useful for me.

Is there any way to change the point with 685 to the first window (1 of 2) instead of (2 of 2) so that I don't need to tab through to get what I want?

What elements decide the pop-up display order of overlapped points?

The order of the data imported into the attribute table?

The latest modified date of the data in the table?

Or is the pop-up order decided just by random and there is no way to make a adjustment?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would expect that the order would be based on the order in the attribute table.  This may be testable by creating a small dataset and adding some overlapping points in different orders, then publish and test.

Comment: I have the same thought. So i checked the OBJECTID of each record since it can tell the order of records in the attribute table, but there is no rule to follow. Sometimes point with larger OBJECTID is on the top sometimes on the bottom, which really confused me.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and, as per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.